# Horizontal Scroll View always scrolling to end when keyboard appear

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, horizontalscrollview, autoscroll

I have 3 `HorizontalScrollview`, for each of them i have `customView` contain `editText` that i add dynamically depend from web service response. The problem is, when i want to change value in `editText` and keyboard appear, the `HorizontalScrollView` scroll automatically to the end, so i can't properly input value to my edit text. My Question is how to prevent autoscroll in my `HorizontalScrollView` so i can input value on my `editText`? and the `HorizontalScrollView` only scroll when user scroll it.

I've search and my problem similar with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28879111/horizontalscrollview-with-edittexts-scrolls-when-keyboard-appear) but the sugestion didn't work. here is workaround that i already try :

1. Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing"` or
   `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"` already try
   `adjustPan` and other combination but it's impact nothing.
2. Add `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in `LinearLayout` inside my `HorizontalScrollView` and it's also impact Nothing.
3. Add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants` the
   `HorizontalScrollView` didn't scroll automatically but i can't change value on my edit text, it similar when i add `android:focusable = "false"` in my `editText`
4. Add code bellow but impact nothing.

   scrollLayout.descendantFocusability = ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS
   scrollLayout.isFocusable = true
   scrollLayout.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
   scrollLayout.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
   v.requestFocusFromTouch()
   false}

Here is My Code

```
private fun setUpList(rootLayout: LinearLayout, scrollLayout: HorizontalScrollView, items: List<ProductItem>) {
    //config horizontal scroll view
    scrollLayout.descendantFocusability = ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS
    scrollLayout.isFocusable = true
    scrollLayout.isFocusableInTouchMode = true
    scrollLayout.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
        v.requestFocusFromTouch()
        false
    }
    // add customView to linear layout
    rootLayout.removeAllViews()
    for (item in items) {
        val view = EditableThumbnailProduct(context)
        view.setProductInfo(item)
        view.setOnProductChangeListener(onChangeListener())
        rootLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        rootLayout.addView(view)
    }
}
```

Here is my XML

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollMed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/contentMed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Here is my custom view

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@color/gray_border"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_product_name"
        style="@style/DefaultTextTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="@string/product_name_label" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_product_stock"
        style="@style/DefaultTextSubTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/available_stock_label" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/gray_border" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_add_to_cart"
            style="@style/WhiteTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button_orange"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/buy_button_label"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_plus_minus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_minus"
                style="@style/WhiteTitle"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_blue"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="11dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="11dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_minus" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
                style="@style/WhiteTitle"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_blue"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txt_cart_amount"
                style="@style/LightTextTitle"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/blue_text_color"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_plus"
                style="@style/WhiteTitle"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_blue"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_plus" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

All sugestion will be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, try the answer from link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298356/android-auto-scroll-when-clicked-on-edittext

Comment: hy @jessica, i want to prevent autoscroll, already edit my thread so other can have better understanding. thx